# DirectX's first frame

Tags: directx, directx-11

I have a DirectX 11.1 application that isn't doing any real real-time rendering.

Instead, I only render if something in the app is changed, grab the output, and save it to disk.

This works perfectly fine, however, not on the first Drawcall.

Here's some pseudocode roughly lining out what I'm doing:

```
// init()
D3D11CreateDevice(...);
dxgidevice1->SetMaximumFrameLatency(0)
createTexture(&rt);  
createStagingTexture(&staging);

// render
immediateContext->SetRenderTarget(rt);
immediateContext->DrawIndexed(...);
d3d11Device->CreateQuery(...)
immediateContext->End(query)
immediateContext->Flush();
while(immediateContext->GetData(query) == S_FALSE) { }
// get bytes
immediateContext->CopyResource(staging, rt);
immediateContext->Flush();
immediateContext->Map(staging, &mapped);
memcopy (mapped.pData) // returns all 0 bytes first time
// copy to preview
immediateContext->SetRenderTarget(staging)       
immediateContext->Map(..)  // constant buffer with shader parameters
immediateContext->Draw(...); // fullscreen quad

memcopy(...)
```

This works perfectly the second and following times i run this, however, the first time memcopy will return an array filled with zeros.

if i change the order to

```
//render
//copy to preview
//get bytes
```

i still get zeroes

```
//render
//copy to preview
//render
//get bytes
```

gives me data.

It seems like i have to do 2 draw calls before actually getting any results, now, if this is the case, i can draw some blanks when the app starts. But i need to be certain that this is by design of the API, and not some fluke that has random results on random devices?

Is there anyone who can shed some light on this issue?

Comment: I can't tell from your snippet, but be sure to check *every* ``HRESULT`` returned from a Direct3D API for failure via the ``FAILED`` macro, the ``SUCCEEDED`` macro, or adopt something like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). There are a lot of points of failure and right now there's no confidence they all work without error checking at runtime.

Comment: there you say something, the draw call itself might fail, didn't think to check if they return HRs. 
All others related to creating objects, i've wrapped to throw .NET exceptions, so those I catch in the debugger and i'm not getting any.

Comment: oh, and that's why i didn't check for HRESULT on the Draw call, they return void..